# При загрузке приложения на GiHub Pages открывается страница с README

Tags: vue.js, github, развертывание, vue3, github-pages

Я пытаюсь загрузить свой vue проект в github pages, но вместо приложения, показывает содержимое файла `README.md`.

**Файл с `index.html` находиться в папке "публичный":**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**То что видно при открытии приложения:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Настройки pages в репозитории:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github pages может брать содержимое приложение только из двух мест:

1. Папки `/docs`
2. Корня репозитория `/`

Соответственно для решения проблемы надо выбрать один из вариантов:

1. Перенос приложения в корень репозитория, т.е index.html и прочее должны быть на одном уровне с `README.md`, `package.json` и др
2. Переименовать папку с приложением на `docs`

Других вариантов не предусмотрено. Ну и конечно после того как вы это сделали, нужно в настройках выбрать или `/` или `/docs`.

Изменения публикуются не сразу, так что после изменений возможно придется подождать некоторое время (до 10 минут). Статус можно посмотреть в разделе деплоя на github pages